# Concat or Merge Two Data Frames with same values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

[Here is the first table(DataFrame) which has the 'sender' column with the value of 79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svLi3.png)

[And Here is the Second table(DataFrame) which has the 'id' column as first column and written with departments,age of employee etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuZI2.png)

[And here is my desired output for these two dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC4uj.png)

My goal is merge or concat two dataframes, sender is a employee id of which sends the message and on employee table it is involved the personal information of employees. At the and I want to call and concatenate message senders with his/her personal info like in the third image. Thank you so much from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your dfs instead of uploading images. Anyhow, considering `df1` your first df and `df2` the second:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='sender',right_on='id', how='left')
```